# Is there a way to tell mongod to log to syslog on another server?

Tags: mongodb, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I want to write mongo logs to syslog on another machine. Reading the mongodb docs, it looks like the only way to use syslog is by writing to the local syslog.

```
systemLog:
  destination: syslog
  syslogFacility: local3
```

A workaround I came up with was to use one of the local facilities, and then use my local syslog to forward the log to the server:

```
#Forward mongodb logs
local3.*       @MY.SYSLOG.SERVER.IP:PORT
```

Is there a way to specify an IP address in mongo.conf so I don't have to do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way in MongoDB to specify a remote server to write to, but you can do the forwarding in syslog.

Update the rsyslog configuration to forward messages like so:

```
if($syslogFacility-text == "local3") then{
  if($syslogTag contains "mongod") then{
    action(type="omfwd" target="MY.SYSLOG.SERVER.IP" port="PORT" protocol="udp")
    stop
  }
}
```

According to [rsyslog docs](https://www.rsyslog.com/sending-messages-to-a-remote-syslog-server/), the `local3.*    @MY.SYSLOG.SERVER.IP:PORT` syntax is deprecated, so use `omfwd` instead.